# Amazon glacier storage upload API method

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-glacier

I am trying to upload the zip file in the vault ( of amazon glacier clould storage ). the upload methods successfully executed without any exception. also return the archive id of the upload but I cant see any files in archives.

```
string vaultName = "test";
            string archiveToUpload = @"E:\Mayur\Downloads\Zip files\search.zip";
            ArchiveTransferManager manager = new ArchiveTransferManager(Amazon.RegionEndpoint.USWest2);
            string archiveId = manager.Upload(vaultName, "Binari archive", archiveToUpload).ArchiveId;
```

I am not getting any exception methods successfully returns an archive Id

Please help me to find out what is the actual issue..

Thanks,
Mayur

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply because The vault inventory is updated approximately once a day.

source: http://aws.amazon.com/glacier/faqs/